# Making bootstrap's popover link clickable?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, popover

It's possible I'm blind, but I've searched for this and can't seem to find an answer.

Using Bootstrap, the format of a popover is pretty simple - add in `rel="popover"` and throw in the content with `data-content="xxx"`

BUT - if you actually click on the link, it goes nowhere. Even with a properly set `href="xxx"`

Am I missing something? I want the popover only on hover, and if a user clicks, I want them to go to whatever link I've set.

Comment: There must be something that you've put that blocks the link. Could you show the HTML and JavaScript ?

Comment: `<a href="http://www.caffeine.com" rel="popover" data-content="Caffeine is the world's favorite drug." data-original-title="Caffeine">Caffeine</a>`

Copy paste that into any stock bootstrap - click on the link, it won't do anything.

Comment: Still don't see anything. Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/hHMK4/). Please provide the JS or any add-on to the default Bootstrap Framework, or reproduce the bug on the fiddle. Either way, this bug doesn't exist in a default environment. Check also your debug console for JS errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your site, in your `application.js` you have that :

```js
// some code has been omitted for clarity
$("a[rel=popover]")
.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
})
```

You just need to remove this `preventDefault` which block your links, or use an alternative way to follow them.